# Dual supply mux dimentioning

Tags: power-supply, mosfet

I would like to design a dual power mux like the ones in the following picture:
[image]

But I do not know how to select resistors (except the partitor in the second circuit) can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The resistors form a resistor divider when EN1 is on (and the n channel FET is on). In that case you want the voltage pulled as low as possible for the p channel fets to turn on. When EN1 is off the gate voltage of the pfets should return to the power rail to fully switch them off.

In short, the gates for the pfets should go to 0V or the supply rail when controlled by EN1.

Because of this a low value for for the lower resistor should be selected and a high value for resistor between the rail and the gates of the pfets.

So something like 100k for the top resistor and 1k for the bottom resistor might work. The last thing to consider is the capacitance which will form an RC filter with a time constant. The time constant should be selected so the pfets are not in the range between fully off and fully on for long (this will depend on the current and the rdson of the fets) because they dissipate a lot of power if they are not fully off or fully on and could potentially exceed thermal ratings.